# 'MetadataPopulator' object has no attribute 'load_metadata_and_associated_files' when trying to compile a tflite model for Coral TPU

Tags: python, tensorflow, metadata, tensorflow-lite

I am trying to convert my TensorFlow Lite model for a Google Choral TPU. I am following this [code](https://colab.research.google.com/github/khanhlvg/tflite_raspberry_pi/blob/main/object_detection/Compile_for_edge_tpu.ipynb), which I found in this [video](https://youtu.be/QqTLkw1IenI) from the official Tensorflow YouTube channel. Everything works fine until I try to compile this part of the code:

```
from tflite_support import metadata

populator_dst = metadata.MetadataPopulator.with_model_file('thenewest_edgetpu.tflite')

with open('thenewest.tflite', 'rb') as f:
    populator_dst.load_metadata_and_associated_files(f.read())

populator_dst.populate()
updated_model_buf = populator_dst.get_model_buffer()
```

where I always get the same error:

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-6-43e0c77c06c5> in <cell line: 5>()
      4 
      5 with open('thenewest.tflite', 'rb') as f:
----> 6   populator_dst.load_metadata_and_associated_files(f.read())
      7 
      8 populator_dst.populate()

AttributeError: 'MetadataPopulator' object has no attribute 'load_metadata_and_associated_files'
```

I've been trying to find a solution, but I have not found one.